# In an excel sheet, Is there a way to populate the country name in the third column while the first two columns are latitude and longitude?

Tags: excel

I have over 20000 entries in an excel sheet. the first two columns are latitude and longitude. Requirement is to populate the country name in the third column? Is there any easy method for me to do so?

Comment: The only thorough way of doing this would be to use the [Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/), but you would need to use VBA for this.

Comment: You could do the heavy lifting in `R` and then import a CSV file into Excel.

Comment: could you please give me some pointers to heavy lifting in R? I means some useful links to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `R` script which makes a call to the Google Maps API with the latitude/longitude values (48.283273, 14.295041), which happens to be inside Austria:

```
> install.packages("RCurl")
> install.packages("rjson")
> library("RCurl")
> library("rjson")

> raw_json <- getURL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=48.283273,14.295041&sensor=false")
> json_data <- fromJSON(raw_json)
> country_name <- json_data$results[[9]]$address_components[[1]]$long_name
[1] "Austria"
```

For your problem, you would need to find a way to do this for all the data points you have, but this is a good starting point.  By the way, I have tested this code and it works.